# Is there a way to search for the cheapest flights regardless of date?

Tags: budget, online-resources, australia

I find myself basing my trips on whenever there's a cheap flight, rather than setting a specific date to have a vacation.

However, it makes it hard for me to do this if I can't search for the cheapest flights regardless of date.

Is there a way to do this?

---

Edit :

I'm from Australia and Australia-specific or international suggestions will both work. However, for the sake of this question as a generic one, I would ask for you to leave any tools you know of regardless of origin, so it might help future viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adioso lets you search for any time. Additionally Skyscanner lets you search across an entire month. Generally Skyscanner has a better range.

[Bren on the road](http://www.brenontheroad.com/guide-getting-super-cheap-flights/) has a good overview of searching for a trip in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are from and where you want to go? For flights around Europe you could try [airixo.com](http://airixo.com/). It will show you all the places you can fly to from your location, when and for how much (you can filter the results by maximum number of changes etc.).

Downsides: it's basically just Europe and it seems they search only low-cost carriers.

Comment: Always best to clarify before answering, if you're not sure of something, rather than putting it in your answer.

Comment: @MarkMayo, I don't think he could comment yet.